# Is it possible to use 'and' or 'or' to join multiple selectors? (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors, find, conditional-statements

I have a jQuery statement like this:

```
$("form[name='formname']").find("input[name*='pwd']");
```

But I want to select all inputs where name contains 'pwd' OR name contains 'user'.  How can do this with jQuery?  is it possible to use operators like && or || to combine selectors?

I want to do something like this:

```
$("form[name='formname']").find("input[name*='pwd'] || input[name=+='user']");
```

Comment: Hint: jQuery selectors are basically CSS selectors.

Comment: jw.. what is `input[name=+='user']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JQuery it's pretty simple actually...

```
jQuery('selector1, selector2, selectorN')
```

Comment: Oh yea, that's it.  $.find("input[name*='pwd'], input[name*='user']") works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To do an "or" use:

```
$("form[name='formname']").find("input[name*='pwd'],input[name=+='user']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just separate your or selectors with a  comma

```
$("form[name='formname']").find("input[name*='pwd'] , input[name=+='user']");
```